# Google two factor authentication not work on 'su' command

Tags: authentication, two-factor-authentication, one-time-password

I installed google two factor authentication on my linux server.
(thanks to: https://github.com/google/google-authenticator-libpam)

When I try to access `root` account via ssh, authenticator works fine.

```
Verification code: .....  
Password: ....   
[root@hostname] works fine :)
```

But!! access other user account and try to access `root` account using `su`,
authenticator only require password.

```
[user@hostname] whoami   
user  
[user@hostname] su  
password: .....  
[root@hostname] What?!!!
```

I set all config to default value.

How can I fix it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default way this works. Since you are using the `google-authenticator-libpam` module you are only adding two factor authentication to the actual external interface login via the addition of `auth required pam_google_authenticator.so` to the `sshd` config file.

The proper security implementation (or at least one of the proper ways) is to not allow external login for the root user, going one step further and locking down ssh to only allow login from users who have two factor authentication enabled is even better.

To do that you would add the following in your `sshd` config :

```
AllowUsers admin bob
```

Answer (score 0):

To enable Google two factor authentication for `su -` you have to add following parameter at the end of file `/etc/pam.d/su` :

```
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so
```

Save it and try login using the normal user and then `su -`, it will prompt for verification code.
i.e. no need to restart `sshd` service.